# Obtaining right value from "JSON-style" NSString in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ios, json

I am trying to get the NSString "Bonjour" from the JSON-style NSString below:

```
[[["Bonjour","Hello","",""]],,"en",,[["Bonjour",[4],1,0,1000,0,1,0]],[["Hello",4,[["Bonjour",1000,1,0]],[[0,5]],"Hello"]],,,,2]
```

Implementing the following code gives me null, assuming result is the NSString above

```
NSDictionary *td = [result JSONValue];
NSLog(@"\n%@", td);
```

How can I grab "Bonjour" from this JSON-style string?

Comment: Use [http://jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com) to validate your JSON string. You’ll notice it’s not valid JSON because of `,,`.

Comment: Can you tell us more about what you are trying to achieve? Where did your string come from? Why do you want to extract "Bonjour" from the string?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is well-formed JSON. For one thing this would return an array.. (surrounded by [], not {}). Also, your arrays have empty entries (',' with nothing separating them)

Are you using SBJSON?

If you consult NSObject+JSON.h you'll see this comment:

```
/// Returns the NSDictionary or NSArray represented by the receiver's JSON representation, or nil on error
```

There has been an error. Check your console output, you should see an error posted there.

Comment: also, not sure what you are trying to achieve. Why are you trying to extract this string from what you posted?

Answer (score 0):

I'm somewhat unsure how the array you posted is a JSON-style NSString, but I believe the NSDictionary you get back should basically store key value pairs exactly as they appeared in the JSON original.  For example, if you had JSON like:

```
{key: "value"}
```

Then you'd get an NSDictionary with a "key" key matched to a value of "value".

Perhaps the reason your NSDictionary is null is because you aren't passing it something that `JSONValue` understands?